# p:autoComplete not working corectly in IE8

Tags: primefaces, autocomplete

I wanted to add a auto complete field to my website and I found p:autoComplete from PrimeFaces. I have never used PrimeFaces before so I followed this [tutorial](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompleteBasic.jsf).

It all seemed to work fine on both IE8 and Chrome as long as I accessed my site through `http://localhost:8080/myWebsite` but when I attempt to access through `http://192.168.34.179:8080/myWebsite` (or from any other computer from my network) auto complete doesn't work on IE8 (it works fine on Chrome).

The website is deployed on GlassFish Server 3.1.2 and I'm using JavaServer Faces 2.1 with PrimeFaces 3.2

Xhtml code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>TPM Log</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="tpm.css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>
        <h:outputText value="Preventive Maintenance Daily Walk Around Log"/>
    </h1>

    <h:form id="AddTpmLog">
        <p:autoComplete id="operator1" value="#{databaseManagedBean.name}"                  
       completeMethod="#{autoCompleteBean.complete}"/>

    </h:form>

</h:body>
```

And Code for the autoCompleteBean:

```
package Beans;

import entities.Operators;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class AutoCompleteBean implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{databaseManagedBean}")
    private DatabaseManagedBean dbBean;

    public List<String> complete(String query) {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Operators operator : dbBean.getOperators()) {

            if (operator.getFirstName().toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase())) {
                results.add(operator.toString());
            } else {
                if (operator.getLastName().toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase())) {
                    results.add(operator.toString());
                }
            }
        }

        return results;
    }

    /**
     * @return the dbBean
     */
    public DatabaseManagedBean getDbBean() {
        return dbBean;
    }

    /**
     * @param dbBean the dbBean to set
     */
    public void setDbBean(DatabaseManagedBean dbBean) {
        this.dbBean = dbBean;
    }
}
```

DatabaseManagedBean is a Bean responsible for communication with MySQL server from which list for auto complete field is being fetched.

I ran out of ideas how it can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.

- You are coupling your view with your database manager bean. I would have a var in the AutoCompleteBean  that stores the value of the field and later use that var as you need,
- I suppose dbBean.getOperators() gets all operators on db. That way you are getting all the data from databse and doing the filter on the view. I would rahter do something like this.

  public List complete(String query){
     List results = new ArrayList();
     for (Operators operator : dbBean.getOperatorsFiltered(query)) {
          results.add(operator.toString());
     return results;
  }

dbBean.getOperatorsFiltered(query) would do the query to the database using the appropiate clasules.

Also be aware that the Primefaces showcase is updated to primefaces 4.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work. I updated PrimeFaces to version 4.0 and simplified method complete but the proplem is still there...

Comment: ¿Can you debug wether the query it's being executed on IE8? Maybe the autocomplete function is not being called at all.

Comment: It is being called. I added System.out.println(query) at the begining of the 'complete' method and I can see in my GlassFish server logs that this line is being executed and value of 'query' is correct.